# Multicolored / Non uniform Gradient

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, processing, p5.js

Looking to create a gradient effect like this either the html canvas or processing.  Multicolored / nonuniform, and somewhat random.  My first inclination is to create several points, assign them a color and a weight, and then interpolate each pixel color on the canvas by a function of 1/R^2 from the each point?

Definitely open to other suggestions.  Thanks!
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you've got an approach you'd like to try. Why don't you just try it? Try something out and post a [mcve] if you get stuck.

Comment: It seems you could get an acceptable effect using built in canvas functions.  You could [create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient) various [gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createRadialGradient) and [mash them together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787899/combining-two-or-more-canvas-elements-with-some-sort-of-blending).

Comment: i think i see several radial grads mixed on top of each other

Comment: This answer will cover some of the techniques you can use to achieve the effect you want. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35526320/3877726 it has a demo snippet and uses masks to layer gradient and variouse composite methods to mix the colours. You can also use clip region rather than masks

Answer (score 0):

I have a little function to create random color-stops for the HTML5 Canvas linear- and/or radial-gradient methods...

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="cnv" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

```
/* simple selection */
var $ = function(a) {return document.getElementById(a.slice(1));};

var randomColorStops = function(num) {
    var arr = [];
    var stops = [];
    var L = num;
    var obj;

    var randomRGB = function() {
        var colorValue = function() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        };
        return 'rgb('+colorValue()+','+colorValue()+','+colorValue()+')';
    };

    while(L--) {
        arr.push(
            parseFloat(
                (Math.random()).toFixed(2)
            )
        );
    }

    arr.sort();
    L = num;

    while(L--) {
        obj = {
            stop: arr[L],
            color: randomRGB()
        };
        stops.push(obj);
    }

    return stops;
}

/* canvas properties */
var canvas = $('#cnv');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var cx = canvas.width / 2;
var cy = canvas.height / 2;
var cr = canvas.height * 0.45;

/* number of stops: random number 5-50 */
var nos = function() {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) + 5;
};

/* create radial gradient */
var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(
    cx - (cr * 0.33),
    cy - (cr * 0.33),
    2,
    cx - (cr * 0.33),
    cy - (cr * 0.33),
    cr * 1.66
);

/* !!! stops = random number of random colour-stops */
var stops = randomColorStops(nos());
var len = stops.length;

/* iterate stops and add to grad */
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    grad.addColorStop(stops[i].stop, stops[i].color);
}

/* draw to canvas */

/* background: black */
ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

/* circle: random gradient */
ctx.fillStyle = grad;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx, cy, cr, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.fill();
```

The function `randomColorStops()` takes a number as an argument (here generated randomly via `nos()`) and returns an array of ordered objects, each with a 'stops' and 'color' property.  This is then iterated and added to the gradient variable (`grad`).

It might be useful to someone [image: dunno??]

See the [jsFiddle of the above code](https://jsfiddle.net/BnPck/5682o2ca/).